# Como remover todos os elementos de uma div em javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom

Como remover de uma vez só todos os elementos de uma div sendo que o [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) remove só um elemento?

Comment: Como você tentou fazer? Você chegou a escrever algum código?

Answer (score 5):

Para remover de uma só vez os descendentes de um elemento defina o valor da propriedade [`innerText`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) desse elemento como uma string vazia.

A propriedade `innerText` retorna o conteúdo do texto do elemento "como renderizado" e
ao ser definida substitui os filhos do elemento pelo valor fornecido.

## Exemplo:

```js
function limpar() {
  let alvo = document.getElementById("alvo");
  
  // Remove todos os descendentes da <div id="alvo">
  alvo.innerText = "";

  console.log(alvo); // Exibe o texto atual da <div>
}
```

```html
<button onclick="limpar()">Limpar div</button>

<div id="alvo">
  <ul>
    <li>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</li>
    <li>Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</li>
    <li>Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</li>
    <li>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</li>
  </ul>
  <svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>      
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para remover todos os elementos, você deve percorrer os elementos filhos através de um laço `for`, removendo-os com o método [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove). Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
function removeAll(){
    const div = document.getElementById("<sua_div>");
    
    for (child of div.children){
        child.remove();
    }
}
```

Uma outra forma bastante simples para apagar todos os elementos filhos da `div`, é utilizando o método [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) do JQuery. Veja abaixo:

```
const div = $("<sua_div>");
div.empty(); // Apagar todos os elementos dentro da div
```

Comment: Se quiser pode pegar os elementos com querySelectorAll("div *") usando o selector *